# match text strings not contained in quotes

Tags: regex

`(?:'.*?')` matches text inside single quotes. I want to match string of text that are not inside quotes though. `[^(?:'.*?')]` is not working for me though: it matches every character that is not a single quote. How can I change it to match text not within quotes?

Comment: `(?:[^'].*?[^'])`   maybe?

Comment: `[]` is a character class. Anything you list in it will be matched against SINGLE characters in the target string. Even if the class contains 500 chars, it's still going to try and match against a single char in the target string only.

Comment: Something like `~(?<![\S'])([^'\s]+)(?![\S'])~` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` to replace all quoted text with empty string to get all the text that is outside quote (*assuming quotes are balanced and unescaped*):

```
$s = "abc '123' foo";
$r = preg_replace("/'[^']*'/", "", $s);
//=> "abc  foo"
```

Comment: ah, will this global match, or should I add a `g` flag to do this multiple times? Thanks!

Comment: PHP doesn't need `g` flag since this regex is already global in nature.

Comment: Can you not use lookahead/lookbehind assertions to do this? I'm not very knowledgeable about the subject, but it seems to have worked for the test cases I tried: https://eval.in/76614 -- not sure if it will work in all other cases, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the purpose of your actions but you could convert the string to Char array and match Unicode codes.

Answer (score 0):

I've never learned the php function/method calls, but the following regex will "capture" the text outside of quotes:

```
(?<=^|\G)(?:'[^']*')?([^']+)
```

as shown in this [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/9kXpqWgY4b)

Answer (score 0):

I think a general purpose way is a loop matching and catenating each group 1 value
Don't need the `\G` anchor because the characters are either quote or not-quote.

```
 #  (?:(?:'[^']*')+|((?:[^']+|'(?![^']*'))+))

 (?:
      (?:
           ' [^']* '
      )+
   |  
      (                             # (1 start)
           (?:
                [^']+               # not '
             |  
                '                   # or, ' not followed by another '
                (?! [^']* ' )
           )+
      )                             # (1 end)
 )
```